# How do I change the text align in my html table that has a textarea

Tags: html, css

In my simple HTML code above is a two column table in HTML with a header row.  First  is a single line height row.  The second line  has height of 7 lines.  My data is the 2nd row, February column is in the middle of the column with space on top and bottom of the text.

How do I put the text so the text is aligned on the top of the column?

I tried `text-align: top`, `verticle-align: top`, and `padding-top: 0px`, but does not work.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:50%">
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align:center">Month</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: top">February</td>
    <td><textarea name="notes" rows="7" maxlength="3000"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `vertical-align` not `verticle-align`

Comment: @RobertWade, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> How do i put the text so the text is aligned on the top of the column?

You can add `vertical-align:top` to vertically align the table data like so:

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:50%">
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align:center">Month</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: top">February</td>
    <td><textarea name="notes" rows="7" maxlength="3000"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it instead of text-align:top

```css
vertical-align:text-top
```